# Proving divisibility of a polynomial by a square of a polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

I need to prove that a polynomial $f \left( x \right) \in \mathbb{Q} \left[ X \right]$ is divisible by a square of a polynomial iff $f$ and $f'$ have a greatest common divisor of positive degree.

I have no idea where to start, except that I have to use the properties of Polynomial Rings as Euclidean Domain.

Comment: The easy direction: Suppose there is some polynomial $g(x)$, which is not a unit,such that $g(x)^2k_1(x)=f(x)$. Then take derivative on both side of the equation to get $2g(x)g'(x)k_1(x)+g(x)^2k_1'(x)=f'(x)$. Well this says that g(x) is a common factor of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$.

Comment: You can find a proof for this in any standard algebra textbook. I came across its proof in the book Algebraic Number Theory and Fermat's Last Theorem by Ian Stewart and David Tall. It's theorem 1.5 in the fourth edition.

Answer (score 2):

Let $q(x)$ be an irreducible common divisor of $f$ and $f'$. Division of $f$ by $q^2$ provides
$$
f=kq^2+r, \quad \text{with}\,\,\,\deg r<\deg q^2
$$
and as $q$ divides $f$, then $q$ divides $r$, and thus
$$
f=kq^2+r_1q, \quad \text{with}\,\,\,\deg r_1<\deg q.
$$ 
Differentiating we obtain
$$
f'=k'q^2+(2kq'+r_1')q+r_1q'
$$ 
But since $q$ divides $f'$, then $q$ divides $r_1q'$, and since $q$ is irreducible, then $q$ divides $q'$or $r_1$. But, $\,deg q>\deg q'$, and hence $q$ does not divide $q'$, as $q'\ne 0$. Hence $q$ divides $r_1$, which implies that $r_1\equiv 0$, since $\deg r_1<\deg q$.

Comment: "Division of $f$ by $q$" should be "Division of $f$ by $q^2$" right? Also, "q divides f', then q' divides $r_1q$' " should be "q divides f' then q divides $r_1q$' "right?

Comment: @mathnoob Yes - I corrected my answer. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* One direction is easy. For the other direction, note that $f$ and $f'$ have a greatest common divisor of positive degree iff $f$ and $f'$ have an *irreducible* common divisor.

Make sure to pinpoint where working over $\mathbb{Q}$ enters in your argument.